# Was there ever an explanation for the change in Ralph's character in the Simpsons?

Tags: character, the-simpsons

In the earlier seasons of the Simpsons there is a version of Ralph that both appears slightly different and acts different. He appears even up to Season 4 Episode 4 *Lisa the Beauty Queen*, which is AFTER normal Ralph Wiggum first appears in Season 4 Episode 1 *Camp Krusty*:

[image: Mail for "Wiggum" is called out and we are shown Ralph]

Which bears some resemblance to the earlier depictions of Ralph:

[image: Earlier depiction of Ralph]

Except this early version of Ralph was able to make more insightful commentary, showing signs of greater intelligence than later depictions of Ralph. In this scene he comments that

> It's recess everywhere but in his heart

In reference to Milhouse losing Samantha. Versus Ralph later:[image: Later depiction of Ralph]

Is there ever an explanation for this?

Comment: https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Ralph_Wiggum#Behind_the_Laughter

Comment: Bit same as Flanders, they took 1 aspect of the character and made it the entire character.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanderization